# Is there a possibility to choose the database and authenticate from within the arangosh?

Tags: arangodb

Is there a possibility to start "arangosh --server.authentication false" and then in the shell change the database and authenticate?

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the database within the shell with `db._useDatabase("myDb")`, but you can not change authentication.

Comment: Thanks. I'll soon open a feature request on github.